# Windows 10 using OpenSSH server, when ssh command is executed, how to prevent pop-up CMD window from appearing

Tags: windows, ssh, cmd, functional-testing, openssh

In Windows 10 using OpenSSH server, when SSH command is executed, a CMD (windows command) window pops up while handling the SSH command.

This can cause issues since I am using the SSH to execute User Interface (UI) tests and the CMD window that pops up can obscure the visual elements of the windows being tested.

SSH Gradle commands are being sent to Windows 10 OpenSSH from Jenkins Server to start UI Functional Tests (AssertJ - Java Swing Application).

Is there any way to get OpenSSH to not pop-up a CMD window?

Environment:
Windows 10,
OpenSSH version 8.0 (http://mirrors.mit.edu/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/)

Comment: Please could you add a little more information? What is causing the SSH command to be executed? Is this part of the test? If so, what technology is starting the SSH command?

Comment: Updated my question to add more detail.  Thanks!

Comment: I would like to add that I have tried to run OpenSSH as a Window 10 service, but that caused the tests to fail since from what I have read online Window 10 Services seem to not have GUI functionality.  Basically if your using OpenSSH to run non-GUI tests this will work, but for Funcitonal GUI tests it will likely fail.